# Move uploaded file in network drive

Tags: php

I don't know what's wrong with my code. I have Z: network drive named ntserver and i want to move file in it. Only working in a local drive such as C and D.

The error displays :

> Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(\ntserver\test\oggy_and_the_cockroaches-wide.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp\www\michael\upload1.php on line 30
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\wamp\tmp\php3FDE.tmp' to
>   '\ntserver\test\oggy_and_the_cockroaches-wide.jpg' in
>   C:\wamp\www\michael\upload1.php on line 30

```
<?
       if(isset($_FILES['image']))


       {
          $errors= array();
          $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
          $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
          $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
          $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];

          $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");



          if($file_size > 2097152) {
             $errors[]='File size must be exactly 2 MB';
          }

          if(empty($errors)==true) {
             move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"\\\\ntserver\test\\".$file_name);
             echo "Success";
          }else{
             print_r($errors);
          }
       }
?>
```

Comment: try to remove last backslash and change path to move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"\\\\ntserver\test\".$file_name);  or replace the "ntserver" with IP address of machine. Next one tip: try to write to Z:\test as you have mounted that drive as letter Z. You also need to check if permissions are valid and have you mounted drive permanently in windows

Comment: @Fiil , yes., i have already tried with Z: and error still the same. i have permission to write a file in Z:

Comment: @Michel make sure the `test` directory exist on remote path and php process has enough rights to write to the path.

Comment: @jagad89 , yes i created a test folder in Z: , what do you mean by enough right to write with php ? how am i supposed to do that. I can write in the Z: test folder

Comment: @MichaelAngeloJopia just right click on the `test` folder-->Properties-->Security tab and give write permission to every user, and try again.

Comment: @jagad89 i have already check it. i have permission to right the file.

Comment: @MichaelAngeloJopia What about the system user rights ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing a back slash. Before trying this make sure that the network location is accessible through cli or run.

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"\\ntserver\test\".$file_name);
```